# Why can't the phrase in code match multivalue fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

[The link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_multivalue_fields_2.html#_multivalue_fields_2) says that a curious thing can happen when using phrase matching on multivalue fields. But in my case, phrase matching couldn't match multivalue fields. The curious thing didn't happen.
Creation and search:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/groups/1 -d '
{
    "names": [ "John Abraham", "Lincoln Smith"]
}
'

curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/groups/_search -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "names": "Abraham Lincoln"
        }
    }
}
'
```

Response:

```
{

    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [ ]
    }

}
```

Not sure where I am wrong? I can't I get the result like the tutorial said? Any help/ pointers is much appreciated.

Note: I running this scripts on Elasticsearch 2.1.1, 2.4.4 and 5.0.1. All the results are the same.

Comment: Try to run match_all query to see if data is for sure there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you're referring to is an old link to the "Definitive guide to ES 2.x" that hasn't been updated yet for ES 5.x. The [official documentation on `position_increment_gap`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/position-increment-gap.html) mentions that the default value is 100.

You can also see this by hitting the `_analyze` endpoint:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
    "text": [ "John Abraham", "Lincoln Smith"],
    "field": "names"
}
```

which produces this (see the position of the third and fourth terms)

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "john",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "abraham",
         "start_offset": 5,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "lincoln",
         "start_offset": 13,
         "end_offset": 20,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 102
      },
      {
         "token": "smith",
         "start_offset": 21,
         "end_offset": 26,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 103
      }
   ]
}
```

So if you add a slop of 100 then you'll find a match:

```
POST my_index/groups/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
         "names": {
            "query": "Abraham Lincoln",
            "slop": 100
         }
      }
   }
}
```